# Convert '{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}' string to date in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert a string with the value '{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}' to a date. I tried to use JSON parse, but the string is an invalid JSON string.

I could add double quotation marks around year, month, and day using:

> replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:([^/])/g, '"$2":$4')

However, I need to add a comma after the values to make it a valid JSON string.

How can I add commas after the values. Or is there another way entirely?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the string coming from? If it is a **secure source** there's always `eval`

Comment: @pilchard How would you use `eval?` if you will try to `eval('{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}')` you will get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'month'`. what am I missing ?

Comment: Yes, I realized after i commented that it is missing commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any advantage of repairing the JSON (unless you can fix the root problem where that is coming from) if you just need to construct a date object in the end. Regex is already a slow operation. No need to add the baggage of serializing and deserializing JSON in js.

```js
  const inputStr = "{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}";

// Use regular expressions with named capture groups to extract values
const regex =
  /year:\s*(\d+)\s*month:\s*(\d+)\s*day:\s*(\d+)/;
const match = regex.exec(inputStr);

if (match) {
  const [, year, month, day] = match;

  console.log("Year:", year);
  console.log("Month:", month);
  console.log("Day:", day);

  const date = new Date(Number(year), Number(month) - 1, Number(day));
  console.log(date);
} else {
  console.log("No match found");
}
```

Comment: You'll note that your month needs to be offset by 1 since months are 0 indexed in JS dates

Comment: I'm getting Property groups does not exist on type 'RegExpMatchArray' and I can't change the target to es2018 or higher.

Comment: I modified it to exec method to find a match, and directly destructuring the captured values without relying on the groups property. TS compiler should be ok with this now. @pilchard thanks for pointing it out. I modified it to offset the month by 1.

Answer (score 2):

### Different approach than the one in the question:

You can use this regex to extract the "key values" parts in your string (you want to get them in order to create object from them) like this  :

```js
const yourString = '{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}';
const regex = /(\w+):\s*(\d+)/g;

const keyValues = yourString.match(regex);
console.log(keyValues)
```

Now you can iterate the keyValues array and build a new object :

```js
const string = '{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}';

const regex = /(\w+):\s*(\d+)/g;
const keyValues  = string.match(regex);

  const obj = {};
  keyValues .forEach(keyValue => {
    const [key, value] = keyValue.split(':');
    obj[key.trim()] = parseInt(value.trim());
  });
  
  console.log(obj)
```

### Answer similar to your approach:

You can work on the original object in order to format it into valid JSON while using the `replace` like this:

```js
const string = '{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}';

const formattedString = string
  .replace(/(\w+)\s*:/g, '"$1":')
  .replace(/(\d+)\s+/g, '$1,')
  .replace(/(\d+)}\s*(\w+)/g, '$1}, "$2":')
  .replace(/}\s*{/g, '}, {')
  .replace(/}\s*{/g, '}, {');

const validJsonObject = `${formattedString}`;
console.log(JSON.parse(validJsonObject));
```

---

Regardless of the approach you are choosing you can now access these object properties, for example:

```js
const string = '{year: 2018 month: 12 day: 5}';

const regex = /(\w+):\s*(\d+)/g;
const keyValues  = string.match(regex);

  const obj = {};
  keyValues .forEach(keyValue => {
    const [key, value] = keyValue.split(':');
    obj[key.trim()] = parseInt(value.trim());
  });
  
  console.log(obj.year) 
  console.log(obj.month)
  console.log(obj.day)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the final result to be of type date